# find repeated letters in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

How do I find repetead/duplicated letters in a dictionary of lists with python? I want to find  equal keys and values . For example:

```
{'C': ['E'], 'D': [A], 'I': ['G', 'N'], 'P': ['A', 'H', 'K', 'L'], 
'S': ['T','V'], 'R': ['J', 'M', 'Q'], 'Z': ['B', 'F', 'O', 'U', 'W', 'X']}
```

In this case the letter A is repeated in dictionary D and P.

How do I this?

Thank you,

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: That error message doesn't match the code you posted. There's no `best_test`, it has a SyntaxError due to the colon after the `append` call, and it doesn't define `w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small twist on @timgb answer is to use [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) in conjunction with [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for example:

```
from collections import Counter

best = {'C': ['E'], 'D': ['A'], 'I': ['G', 'N'], 'P': ['A', 'H', 'K', 'L'],
        'S': ['T', 'V'], 'R': ['J', 'M', 'Q'], 'Z': ['B', 'F', 'O', 'U', 'W', 'X']}

counts = sum((Counter(v) for v in best.values()), Counter())
repeated = set(e for e, count in counts.iteritems() if count > 1)

print repeated
print [k for k, values in best.iteritems() if repeated.intersection(values)]
```

**Output**

```
set(['A'])
['D', 'P']
```

**Explanation**

You can use `sum` with `Counter` because `Counter` implements the `__add__` method, just need to provide the default value to `sum`, in this case an empty Counter. Once you have the counts you can get the elements with count greater than one with the generator expression.

**Note**

These code outputs both the repeated elements and the keys that contain those repeated elements in this case `['D', 'P']`

Comment: Using `sum` like that is ok if the length of `best` is small, but it doesn't scale well because it's a [Shlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Comment: @PM2Ring I see, so using update scales better?

Comment: I think so. On second thoughts, using `sum` here may not be as bad as I first thought, since it mutates the values of the original Counter, so it's not quite the same as using `sum` to concatenate lists. Or to concatenate strings, which `sum` refuses to do.

Comment: Thank you a lot...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can apply a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to the un-nested `best.values()` and keep the items that occur more than once.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain # for un-nesting
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> best = {'C': ['E'], 'D': ['A'], 'I': ['G', 'N'], 'P': ['A', 'H',  'K', 'L'], 'S': ['T','V'], 'R': ['J', 'M', 'Q'], 
...:'Z': ['B', 'F', 'O', 'U', 'W', 'X']}
...:
>>> dupes = [k for k,v in Counter(chain.from_iterable(best.values())).items() if v > 1]
>>> dupes
>>> ['A']
```

In this demo, the un-nesting is done with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) but you can also write a simple `for` loop in which you `update` the counter.

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for sub in best.values():
...:    c.update(sub)
...:    
>>> dupes = [k for k,v in c.items() if v > 1]
>>> dupes
>>> ['A']
```

I can update this answer once you show us the expected output.

Comment: Hi, that's it... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the nested lists into a single one, use `count` to tally each item, then print the highest value in that with `max`:

```
from collections import Counter

best = {'C': ['E'], 'D': ['A'], 'I': ['G', 'N'], 'P': ['A', 'H',  'K', 'L'], 'S': ['T','V'], 'R': ['J', 'M', 'Q'], 'Z': ['B', 'F', 'O', 'U', 'W', 'X']}

flat_list = [item for sublist in [best[b] for b in best] for item in sublist]
print max([[flat_list.count(x),x] for x in set(flat_list)])
```

Comment: Why not `for sublist in best.itervalues()` ?

Comment: Thank you all...